# Unable to find pdo_mysql adapter when integrating Doctrine2 into Lithium w/ li3_doctrine2 module

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, lithium

** Update: This turned out to be somehow related to an incompatibility with the copy of lithium I was using the li3_doctrine2 module with. After pulling from the [lithium framework repo](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework) and adding the doctrine module as a submodule it seems to be working correctly. And I am aware that I setup the example model and controller below incorrectly.

I have been trying to use Doctrine2 with li3 using the [li3_doctrine2 module](https://github.com/mariano/li3_doctrine2). I have been following the instructions on the github page for the module, but keep running into the error:

```
Could not find adapter `pdo_mysql` in class `lithium\\data\\Connections'
```

I checked phpinfo and confirmed that pdo_mysql is being loaded. Right now I am just working with a basic model that extends \li3_doctrine2\models\BaseEntity:

```
namespace app\models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="cn_blog_entries")
 */
class BlogEntries extends \li3_doctrine2\models\BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

            /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $uristub;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $content;

            /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date_publish;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $active;

            /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $timestamp_created;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $timestamp_updated;

}
```

In my controller I'm keeping it pretty basic for testing:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\BlogEntries;
// use app\models\BlogEntryTags;

class BlogController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function index() {
        $entries = BlogEntries::getRepository()->findBy();
        var_dump($entries);
    }
}
```

I have been coming back to this issue for weeks now. If I can't figure it out, I guess it means no Doctrine2 in Lithium for me. I wish lithium's ORM had better relationship support!